# Order second level array values based on a keyword

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort the second-level values based on a specific keyword. In this case that keyword is `red`.

If I inspect the steps in the callback function it seems to work, but the final result is unchanged. It also sorts the top-level keys alphabetically.

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'red', 'green'
    ),
    'bar' => array(
        'yellow', 'red'
    ),
);

print_r($data);

uasort($data, function($data) {
    $matches = preg_grep("/red/", $data);

    $rest = array_diff($data, $matches);

    $order = array_merge($matches, $rest);

    return $order;

});

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as intended because `uasort()` only sorts the array you pass to it in the first argument, the first level array ($data). The rest of your code, although running and syntactically correct, does not help either.

Here is a working example :

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'red', 'green'
    ),
    'bar' => array(
        'yellow', 'red'
    ),
);

array_walk($data,function(&$v){
    uasort($v,function($a,$b){
        return preg_match('/red/',$a)?-1:1;
});});

print_r($data);
```

- array_walks() iterates through the first-level array.
- uasort() is provided in the callback, and handles the sorting part of the second-level arrays.
- preg_match() is then used to match the string and return a value suitable for reordering in the callback to `uasort()`.